# eval() JavaScript Memory Leak

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, memory-leaks, eval

I have a private client sending my server javascript as a string to execute. This is working as intended, however, every time I send a payload of JS to the server, the memory increases, but my memory usage never falls back down.

Here is the node.js code:

```
app.post(`/`, (req, res) => {
  const final = req.body.toString();
    function executeJS(str) {
    return new Function(`'use strict'; ${str}`)();
  }
  res.status(200).json(executeJS(code)).end();
});
```

I have attached a screenshot of my memory usage. As you can guess, right around 8:45 I sent several requests the server. The memory goes up and continues at that level long after the request is processed.

[memory usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8aKh.png)

Comment: yikes this is a huge security vulneability.

Comment: private client - private server. do you have an answer or did you just skim?

Comment: just calling it out. never ever stays "private"

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  This would be the way it works.  Javascript code (once loaded and compiled in nodejs) is not garbage collected so the more code you run this way, the more code will be stored by your process.

For safety, security and memory management, you could run this code in a child_process or WorkerThread and then recycle (destroy and recreate) that child or worker every so often to get rid of old code.

Also, when looking for memory leaks, you cannot judge a leak just because memory usage went up and stayed up.  A memory leak is only proven when memory usage just keeps going up and up over time.  A situation where memory rises, but doesn't go back down can be a process just not returning unused memory back to the OS, but that memory is available for reuse within the process.  This would not be an actual leak.   So, you also have to make sure you have an actual leak.

But, the situation you described of continually running more and more code does sound to me like it would create a situation like a leak where more and more memory is consumed.  This usage model is not something that node.js is particularly designed for.  So, you'd have to use a work-around like a WorkerThread (which is a separate V8 instance) or a child process (also a separate V8 instance) that you can nuke every once in awhile to reclaim memory used by old code.

---

I will also add that is very unusual to have a server accept code from the outside world and "just run" it within your main server process.  As others have mentioned, this architecture has all sorts of security vulnerabilities, no matter what precautions you take.  It is much more common to send data and then you run code that processes the data or if you really have to accept unknown code from the outside world to then run that in another process, perhaps even a sandboxed process to protect the server from anything it might do - whether accidental crashing, accidental bugs (like a stuck `while` loop) or doing something malicious.

Comment: Not doubting you in the slightest, as your answer matches up exactly to a recent experience, but do you know of any documentation/articles that cover your point of "Javascript code (once loaded and compiled in nodejs) is not garbage collected" in more depth? I'd like to know a bit more about how nodejs deals with eval, and why it behaves that way, and I'm struggling to find anything that covers it adequately.

Comment: @Hecksa - I don't know of any documentation related to `eval()` and garbage collection.  You can run some exctreme experiments (perhaps `eval()` used in a large loop) to measure the behavior.

Comment: @Hecksa - Although, come to think of it, I believe that nodejs uses `eval()` when it runs `require()` to load a CommonJS module and that's the data where my original answer comes from.

Comment: Appreciate the pointers, thanks